# Plesk, FTP denied access to www-data files

Tags: linux, plesk

I've been running Plesk on Ubuntu for a long while, files that are created by PHP as www-data are accessible via FTP (ProFTPd). However, we have a new server up now running Plesk on Debian instead, and now I get "permissions denied" whenever I try to access or delete any www-data files.

The file permissions, file owners and file groups are the same. ProFTPd seems to be running with identical configurations and I really can't seem to find out why it works on the old, but not the new. Does this have something to do with Debian?

Both servers run the same Plesk version (the old working one has been upgraded from Plesk 8 over time though), as far as I can tell I can't find any difference that would cause this behavior (I'm not super familiar with linux). I've searched for solutions on the net too but all I find is manually changing the users/groups or setting 777, neither of which seems like a good solution.

Comment: Generally www-data files can only be accessible though FTP if some access rights are explicitly given to a FTP user. Are you completely sure privileges are identical on both systems? This might have been tricked on old systems including FTP user in www-data group...

Comment: @SergeyL sorry for the late reply! I checked the users and groups files in etc as well, same setup, the www-data user is set for the ftp-group on both servers. And both are regular plesk installs so I don't see why there would be any difference (and I can't find any), other than some than due to upgrading or different OSes.